# Android: GATT 137 exception when read characteristic

Tags: java, android, kotlin, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm connecting bluetotooth device. I'm getting GATT 137 exception when I read characteristic of bluetooth device. Why I can't read characteristic ?
Code snippet:

```
if (!mBluetoothGatt.readCharacteristic(mCharacteristic)) {
     Log.e(TAG, "read characteristic task is success")
    }else{
     Log.e(TAG, "read characteristic task is fail")
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

code 137 is AUTHORIZATION_FAILED. So you probably need to bond with your device first.